# How can i create a sticky tabhost on android applications?

Tags: android-tabhost, sticky

I want to create a tabhost that can be sticky under the action bar, here is some concept image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDh4U.png

this is the normal condition of the view, the app will have some other content above the tabhost, which the coding is also include in the tab activity and the app will have few tabs and each tabs will use listview to show the information.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZCn1.png

i want the tabhost will be sticky just under the action bar when i scroll down the listview, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager** a good example of scrolling tab header by [kmshack Github page](https://github.com/kmshack)

The Sample code is give in this [Here Git Hub link](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager)

[image]

The explanation for the solution is begin described in the github page

Hope this will help you